# React navigation bar header has a margin on the left

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using `React-Navigation` and `StackNavigator` to implement a navigation bar at the top of my react native app, which shows the app logo centered and a menu button on the right. I cannot get it to take up the complete space of the header container though, there is always a margin of ~20px on the left.

As you can see in my code, I have already applied all kinds of style properties such as `margin: 0`, `padding: 0`, `alignment: fill` and `width:100%` to `headerStyle`, `headerContainerStyle` and the navigation bar component itself, but none of them helped.

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import {Home} from "components/Home";
import {NavigationBar} from "components/NavigationBar";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer headerStyle={styles.container}>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home" headerStyle={styles.container}
        screenOptions={{
                        headerTitleContainerStyle: styles.container,
                        headerTitleStyle: styles.title,
                        headerStyle: styles.header,
                        headerTitle: props => <NavigationBar {...props} />
                      }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignment: 'fill',
    width: '100%',
    height:'100%',
    // useless
    margin: 0
  },
  title: {
  },
  header: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    // useless
    padding: 0,
    margin: 0,
    marginLeft: 0,
    alignment: 'fill',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center'
  }
});
```

*NavigationBar.jsx:*

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

import { CenteredView } from 'shared/view/CenteredView'; // just a wrapper for View
import { FlexImage } from "shared/image/FlexImage"; // just a wrapper for Image
import { PLACEHOLDER } from "assets/images";

export const NavigationBar = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.barContainer}>
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green'}} />
            <CenteredView style={{flex: 2, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
                <FlexImage source={PLACEHOLDER} />
            </CenteredView>
            <CenteredView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
                <Button title="Menu" color="#000" />
            </CenteredView>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    barContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        // useless
        alignment: 'fill',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        padding: 0,
        margin: 0,
        marginLeft: 0
    }
});
```

I assigned different colors to the containers and views to demonstrate the issue. The red column is what is wrong:

[image: Margin issue, tested in Chrome's mobile device simulator]

---

***UPDATE:*** I noticed that I can swipe the complete page to the left so that the margin disappears and the very left of the content container (in aqua blue) disappears, leaving a blank area on the right (see picture below). This only works in the mobile device simulator in Chrome. On my Android phone I still have the margin but cannot swipe.

[image: Swiped to the left]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using the `header` property rather than `headerTitle` to declare `NavigationBar` as my custom header component.

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        screenOptions={{
                        headerStyle: styles.header,
                        header: props => <NavigationBar {...props} /> // <------- here
                      }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

I find the [documentation of StackNavigator options](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#navigationoptions-used-by-stacknavigator) a bit confusing. From my understanding, the difference between `header` and `headerTitle` is that `headerTitle` may also be a string and defaults to the scene title if the header component is not available. But that doesn't really explain the differences in layout. In the [code example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers#replacing-the-title-with-a-custom-component) `headerTitle` is used.

Answer (score 0):

Tried `header` Component but content went to the next line, would be glad if someone could suggest a better way to handle this case

[image]

**Solution:** I used `headerTitle` Component but with a little modification on **right padding** to workaround this issue.

[image]

I would like to suggest [React navigation Team](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator) to provide more control over   styles please.